# u"The authority ({0}) is not valid.".format( - Error trying install pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I justing trying install pip "`python get-pip.py`".

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 22312, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 197, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip._internal
  File "c:\users\italo~1.siq\appdata\local\temp\tmp1lyoms\pip.zip\pip\_internal\
__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "c:\users\italo~1.siq\appdata\local\temp\tmp1lyoms\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\ur
llib3\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\italo~1.siq\appdata\local\temp\tmp1lyoms\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\ur
llib3\connectionpool.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "c:\users\italo~1.siq\appdata\local\temp\tmp1lyoms\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\ur
llib3\packages\rfc3986\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "c:\users\italo~1.siq\appdata\local\temp\tmp1lyoms\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\ur
llib3\packages\rfc3986\api.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "c:\users\italo~1.siq\appdata\local\temp\tmp1lyoms\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\ur
llib3\packages\rfc3986\iri.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "c:\users\italo~1.siq\appdata\local\temp\tmp1lyoms\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\ur
llib3\packages\rfc3986\exceptions.py", line 19
    u"The authority ({0}) is not valid.".format(
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't understand this problem.

My python version is 3.2.4 because my computer just accepted it.

I downloaded the pip from here: `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`

Comment: 3.2.4 is a horribly old version. You really want at least 3.4.

Comment: Not only is 3.2 horribly old, the minimum version for the current pip is 3.5. You cannot install it for 3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your error is indeed in your Python version 3.2.4:

The Unicode literal 'u' for strings was (re)[introduced](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/) in [version 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html) and simply isn't part of the syntax of your version, hence the error.